# 'Connecting...' Smartfoxserver 2

Tags: connection, ip, smartfoxserver

When i try to launch an example it just says 'Connecting...'
I've set my server IP to be 127.0.0.1 which is default obviously
and it's also set to connect to that with the port 3993 and I've also tried the default one but still no luck.

I've also tried the default settings, fresh install, but still nothing was working, i could connect to my admin panel fine, but still nothing on the examples.

The last thing i tried was my IP-4 address with port 22 and nothing happened again.

Any fixes?

Comment: For the record i checked all the other questions out and none helped fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default port for Smartfoxserver is 9933